# Get joomla 2.5 username using php and pass it to session or variable

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am a newbie here, I wanna learn p-h-p. I am using joomla2.5.9 right now, but i wanna get current username who logged in and put it in variable or maybe put it in a session. What i want from this current username is to create another script using p-h-p based on that current username.

first question : How can i Do that?
Second question: where should i put that 'first question' script in joomla2.5.9 folder?

Please Help... and thanks in advance..

By,

Leo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PHP code, shows you the name of current user.

`<?php $user =& JFactory::getUser();`
`$userName = $user->get( 'name' );`
`if ($user->get('guest') == 1) {} else {`
`echo "Hi ".$userName."! Welcome to our great website!";`
`}`
`?>`

You can put this code in your template files in: /templates/yourtemplatename/filewhereyouwanttoaddthis.php (in your case I think that you'll want to put this code in index.php - the principal layout of site)

Comment: Yes, it is working now, but when I try to put it in session, i can't get the session.. I add session_start(); at the beginning of index.php file. and then tried to echo the session in a new file..but no echo i get from it.. Please help again...

Comment: can you paste here your code? I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I think that this is what you want: <?php
$user =& JFactory::getUser(); $userName = $user->get( 'name' ); session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $userName;
echo '<br /><a href="otherpage.php?' . SID . '">Link to other page</a>'; ?> AND OtherPage.php content: <?php
session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>. It's ok?

Comment: what i want is to set $_SESSION['username'], which i got from that index.php, and available for all files i want to create later.. so example if i create 2 external php files later and i want to get this session, I just simply use session_start();

Comment: You need to call session_start() in all php files you want.

Comment: <?php $user =& JFactory::getUser(); $userName = $user->get( 'name' ); session_start(); $_SESSION['username'] = $userName; echo '<br /><a href="otherpage.php?' . SID . '">Link to other page</a>'; ?> AND OtherPage.php content: <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>   

I tried this code, but when it opened the new file (test.php), it gives empty response when i opened it in browser

Comment: do i have to change that SID??

Comment: I need to get $_SESSION['username'] outside joomla framework.. Please Help

Comment: You may try this:  Include("filewhereissessionmemored.php");. So you cand create session in filewhereissessionmemored.php and include them in otherfile.php. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: This is an example code, where (if it works for you) you will put at sessions the username like before. <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['example']="yes";

Include("otherfile.php");

?>

Session variable will be available in included file.